# RibbonControl is stretching image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I'm using the Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon in my WPF application, and it is stretching the RibbonCommand image larger than it is supposed to be. The image is inserted as follows:

```
<r:RibbonApplicationMenu.Command>
     <r:RibbonCommand LargeImageSource="/Resources/Images/FSRibbon.png" />
</r:RibbonApplicationMenu.Command>
```

Here is FSRibbon.png:  [image]
It is a 32x28 32 bit png. I have also tried exactly 32 x 32, as well as a 48 x 48 with empty padding around it. No matter what I do, the ribbon control is displayed as this:

[image]

As you can see, it's getting blown up as though it's being stretched to a 48x48 canvas. But if I provide a 48x48 image, it blows that up just as much. The RibbonCommand doesn't provide any way to control the stretch of the image, so there's nothing like `<Image/>` object's `Stretch="None"` property for me to set. What is going on?

---

**Attempts**

I've tried this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried SmallImageSource and just not give it a LargeImageSource?

Comment: SmallImageSource is a property for something different. If you're using a ribbon button, setting SmallImageSource instead of LargeImageSource leaves the image blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356750/wpf-strange-image-stretching-in-buttons) question tipped me off to the fact that WPF isn't so magical at adapting to different image resolutions (DPI / pixels per inch, etc). The aforementioned question said that the Windows standard is 96 DPI, which I guessed was a synonym for pixels/in. The image I uploaded above happens to be 72 pixels/in.

I tried converting it to 96 using 'scale image' in GIMP (open source image editor), and magically, it started being treated properly.

[image]  **-->** [image]

As if us humble programmers are expected to know this junk :p